# How to get the first cell in range which value is equal to a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to write this function which ideally will return the range of a cell in a google spreadsheet. I think the code I came up with is okay and would usually work, but  unfortunately, because of this code the script is exceeding the time limits.

Therefore I am wondering if there's a better (and most importantly faster) way to get the position of the cell in question.

Here is the code I've got :

```
   function appendNewToDashboardSS (folderId){

           var folderName = DriveApp.getFolderById('***').getName();


          var latestFileId = getLatestFileId('***');//get the id of the last uploaded file in the folder
          Logger.log(latestFileId);

          var formatedName = DriveApp.getFileById(latestFileId).getName().replace(".csv", "");//format the name so it doesn't include the .csv part

          DriveApp.getFileById(latestFileId).setName(formatedName);//set the name


          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(latestFileId);//open the file
          var rangeStart = 0;
          var rowCount = ss.getLastRow();
          for (i=1; i <= rowCount; i++) {

           var cellValue = ss.getRange("A" + i).getValue(); 

          if(cellValue===formatedName){
            rangeStart = i; //this is where the needed range would start

            break;
          } 
        } 
       Logger.log("range start" + rangeStart);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should read the entire sheet data and loop into the resulting array instead of getting each cell data one by one. The speed difference will be really noticeable.
This should do the job :

```
function appendNewToDashboardSS (folderId){
  var folderName = DriveApp.getFolderById('***').getName();
  var latestFileId = getLatestFileId('***');//get the id of the last uploaded file in the folder
  Logger.log('latestFileId='+latestFileId);
  var formatedName = DriveApp.getFileById(latestFileId).getName().split(".csv")[0];//keep only the part before .csv part
  DriveApp.getFileById(latestFileId).setName(formatedName);//set the name
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(latestFileId);//open the file
  var rangeStart;
  var data = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i=0; i <= data.lengt-1; i++) {
    var cellValue = data[i][0];  
    if(cellValue.split('.csv')[0]==formatedName){
      rangeStart = i+1; //this is where the needed range would start
      break;
    } 
  } 
  Logger.log("range start" + rangeStart);
}
```